# How to add a signature (author name, place, date) to a preface?

Tags: xetex, koma-script, book-design, scrbook, signatures

I want to have a book preface signed with author (the prefaces’s, not the book’s), date and place name.  I am using Koma-script, but could use a different package as it is quite a simple book.  Does any package have a standard way of doing that?

Comment: why not just, at the end of the prefacer, add the extra information as, for example `\begin{flushright} author name\\date\\place\par\end{flushright}`.  you probably want to add some `\vspace` before the signature block.

Comment: LaTeX does provide the most basic stuff with the most basic layout. Every special layout stuff has to be done by the user. Though admittedly, some packages provide layout stuff.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, it seems date and place are only scrlttr2 variables, while I am using scrbook.  Not that I cannot write date and place as I want them explicitly.

Comment: If you want to use `scrlttr2` variables with another class, you can use package `scrletter`. But if you just want the current date, `\today` should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here what I ended up wiþ:

```
\medskip
\begin {flushright}
  Leandro Guimarães Faria Corcete \textsc {Dutra}, Brasília, fim da seca
  de 2017.
\end {flushright}
```

Comment: You don't need the `\par` at the end. `\end{flushright}` uses `\endtrivlist`. `\endtrivlist` automatically adds `\par` in horizontal mode.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the German KOMA-Script guide uses

```
 \bigskip\noindent
 Markus Kohm, Neckarhausen bei eisigen Temperaturen im Januar 2017
```

at the end of the preface.

If you want the date of the LaTeX run, you can use

```
\bigskip\noindent
My Name, \today, somewhere
```

If you want several lines

```
\medskip
\begin{flushleft}
  My Name\par
  \today\par
  Somewhere
\end{flushleft}
```

or

```
\medskip
\begin{flushleft}
  My Name\\
  \today\\
  Somewhere
\end{flushleft}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Schweinebacke, you helped a lot to build my solution.